# Space efficient embedded Haskell persistence solution

Tags: haskell, persistence, nosql

I'm looking for a persistence solution (maybe a NoSQL db? or something else...) that has the following criteria:

1) Has a Haskell API

2) Is disk space efficient--the db could easily get to many gigabytes of data but I need it to run well on a typical desktop. I need something that stores the data as efficiently as possible. So, for example, storing field names in a record would be bad.

3) High performance for reading sequential records. The typical use case is start somewhere and then read forward straight through the data--reading through possibly millions of records as quickly as possible.

4) Data is basically never changed (would only be changed if it was discovered data was incorrect somehow), just logged

5) It should act directly on file(s) that can be easily moved/copied around. It should not be calling a separate running server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the "single file" requirement with no other running process, everything else can be fulfilled by every standard RDBMS, and depending on the type of data, sometimes *especially* well by columnar stores in particular.

The only single-file solution I know of is sqlite. Mainly sqlite founders when a single db needs to be accessed by multiple concurrent processes. If that isn't the case, then I wouldn't be surprised if you could scale it up singificantly.

Additionally, if you're only looking for sequential scans and key-value stores, you could just go with berkeleydb, which is known to be high-performance for very large data sets.

There are high quality Haskell bindings for talking to both sqlite and berkeleydb.

Edit: For sequential access only, its also blindingly straightforward to roll your own layer with the binary or cereal packages -- you basically need to write a helper function to wrap reading records from a file sequentially rather than all at once. An abstraction for folding over them is nice as well. Then you can decide to append to a single file, or spread your writes across files as you go. Either way, that's the most lightweight and straightforward option of all. The only drawback is having to worry about durability -- safe writes in the presence of interrupts, and all that other stuff that a good DB solution should take care of for you.

Comment: Thank you. I should have specified that it will only be accessed by a single application. It's for an embedded db in a desktop application. BerkeleyDB won't work due to licensing--in case in the future I want to redistribute the app. I'll look into sqlite

Answer (score 3):

CouchDB ticks most of your boxes:

1) http://hackage.haskell.org/package/CouchDB

2) Depends on how you use it.  You can store any binary data in it, but its up to you to know what it means.  Or you can store XML or JSON, which is less space efficient but easier to migrate as your schema evolves (which it will).

3) Don't know, but its used for big web sites.

4) CouchDB uses a CM-like concept of updates and baselines, so old data stays around.  It can be purged later as obsolete, but I think thats optional.

5) No.  Its written in Erlang and runs (I believe) as a separate process.  But why is that a problem?

Comment: Erlang isn't a problem, but... it's an embedded db for a desktop application and I don't want to deal with managing a server running and such. Sounds like couchdb would work except #5. sqlite is looking like it might fit the bill really well, though